# When I run the code below, it doesn't recognize the username on WHERE clause. Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

sorry to bother you again.

On our survey app, when a user logs in and takes one of our surveys, the code below is supposed to grade the survey based on the user who took it and the surveyId.

These are declared as session variables.

However, the code, for some reason, isn't recognizing either the surveyId or the username of the user who is taking this survey.

As a result, it is showing duplicate answers for each user.

I am attempting to post a screenshot but I am having difficulties.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
'//first the surveyId and username are declared in pageLoad event:

        If Session("UserName") Is Nothing Or Session("Username") = "" Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?redirect=List.aspx")
        Else
            userLB.Text = "You are logged in as " & Session("FullName")
            userLB.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange
        End If
```

'//Then the code in gridview:

```
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="WITH CorrectChoices AS
(
  SELECT Distinct QuestionID, LEFT(CorrectChoice , LEN(CorrectChoice )-1) AS Choice
  FROM SurveyChoices AS extern
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT Choice + ', '
    FROM SurveyChoices AS intern
    WHERE extern.QuestionID = intern.QuestionID
    AND intern.IsCorrect=1
    ORDER BY Choice
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) pre_trimmed (CorrectChoice)
  GROUP BY QuestionID, CorrectChoice
)
, Answer AS
(
  SELECT QuestionID, UserName, LEFT(CorrectChoice , LEN(CorrectChoice )-1) AS Choice
  FROM SurveyAnswers AS extern
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT Choice + ', '
    FROM SurveyAnswers intern
    INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC ON SC.QuestionId = intern.QuestionID
                               AND SC.ChoiceID = intern.ChoiceID
    WHERE extern.QuestionID = intern.QuestionID
    ORDER BY Choice
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) pre_trimmed (CorrectChoice)
  GROUP BY QuestionID, UserName, CorrectChoice
) 

SELECT SQ.Question, CC.Choice, A.Choice Answer, 
       CASE WHEN CC.Choice = A.Choice THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Wrong' END AS Status
FROM SurveyQuestions SQ
LEFT JOIN CorrectChoices CC ON CC.QuestionID = SQ.QuestionID
LEFT JOIN Answer A ON A.QuestionID =SQ.QuestionID
WHERE SQ.SurveyID = @SurveyId AND UserName=@UserName">
<SelectParameters>
 <asp:SessionParameter Name="UserName" SessionField="UserName" />
 <asp:SessionParameter Name="SurveyId" SessionField="SurveyId" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.

Just adding intern.UserName = @Username fixed the problem to inner query.

SELECT Choice + ', '
FROM SurveyAnswers intern
INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC ON SC.QuestionId = intern.QuestionID
                           AND SC.ChoiceID = intern.ChoiceID **and intern.UserName = @UserName**
WHERE extern.QuestionID = intern.QuestionID